# Javascript / jQuery function similar to Liquid: cycle

Tags: javascript, jquery, iteration, liquid, cycle

Is there a function in JavaScript/jQuery similar to Liquid *[**cycle**](https://help.shopify.com/themes/liquid/tags/iteration-tags#cycle)* as described below?

Loops through a group of strings and outputs them in the order that they were passed as parameters. Each time cycle is called, the next string that was passed as a parameter is output.

Input:

```
{% cycle 'one', 'two', 'three' %}
{% cycle 'one', 'two', 'three' %}
{% cycle 'one', 'two', 'three' %}
{% cycle 'one', 'two', 'three' %}
```

Output:

```
one
two
three
one
```

I have been trying to look at [`loop`](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_loop_for.asp), [`forEach`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_forEach.asp), [`do/while`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_dowhile.asp) but can't get the idea.
Thanks for any suggestion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a closure,
inside the outer scope you define a variable which keeps track of the index;
while the returned function increments or resets the index,
and returns the corresponding item.

Here's an example:

```js
function cycle(arr) {
  cycle.i = -1

  //return a closure for cycling
  return function() {
    cycle.i = cycle.i < arr.length - 1 ? cycle.i + 1 : 0

    return arr[cycle.i]
  }
}

var it = cycle(['one', 'two', 'three'])
setInterval(function() {
  console.log(it())
}, 500)
```

Comment: It works! Never thought about the closure. Thanks a lot for the quick answer.